# Im having an issue when I attempt to update my gemfile in order to link it to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '=> 3.6.2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '3.0.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '5.0.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '2.5.0'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Twitter Bootstrap library for front-end UI and layout
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'

# Use Font Awesome saas gem for adding icons
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.6.2'

# Use Hirb for better database table display in console
gem 'hirb', '0.7.3'

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  # Use the PostgreSQL gem for Heroku production servers
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end  

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
ruby '~> 2.5.6'
```

That's how my gemfile currently looks. I had to update my ruby version from 2.3.0 to 2.5.6, so I could use it with Heroku. When I run a bundle install it would read an error message.

*Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.5.6*

So I researched how to fix that on stackoverflow, and used

```
rvm install 2.5.6
rvm use 2.5.6
```

That seemed to solve the issue until I ran bundle install and got an error saying

*An error occurred while installing puma (3.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.6.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds
before bundling.*

I ran

```
gem install puma -v 3.6.2
```

Then got this error message....

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.6/gems/puma-3.6.2/ext/puma_http11
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.6/bin/ruby -I /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20190915-17642-pmnry4.rb extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.6/gems/puma-3.6.2/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.6/gems/puma-3.6.2/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
In file included from ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:7:0:
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl: In function ‘puma_parser_execute’:
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:111:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c: In function ‘get_dh1024’:
mini_ssl.c:90:5: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘DH {aka struct dh_st}’
   dh->p = BN_bin2bn(dh1024_p, sizeof(dh1024_p), NULL);
     ^~
mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init_server’:
mini_ssl.c:139:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   ID sym_cert = rb_intern("cert");
   ^~
mini_ssl.c:144:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   ID sym_ca = rb_intern("ca");
   ^~
mini_ssl.c:166:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   DH *dh = get_dh1024();
   ^~
mini_ssl.c:170:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   EC_KEY *ecdh = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp521r1);
   ^~~~~~
mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init_client’:
mini_ssl.c:197:3: warning: ‘DTLSv1_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   conn->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_method());
   ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/bio.h:13,
                 from mini_ssl.c:14:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1870:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.0 */
 ^
mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_shutdown’:
mini_ssl.c:333:8: warning: unused variable ‘buf’ [-Wunused-variable]
   char buf[512];
        ^~~
mini_ssl.c:332:11: warning: unused variable ‘err’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int ok, err;
           ^~~
mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init’:
mini_ssl.c:350:8: warning: unused variable ‘buf’ [-Wunused-variable]
   char buf[512];
        ^~~
mini_ssl.c:349:11: warning: unused variable ‘err’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int ok, err;
           ^~~
mini_ssl.c:349:7: warning: unused variable ‘ok’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int ok, err;
       ^~
mini_ssl.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
Makefile:242: recipe for target 'mini_ssl.o' failed
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.6/gems/puma-3.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.6/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/puma-3.6.2/gem_make.out
```

What is the best route to solve this issue, so that I can link my project to Heroku?

Comment: "What is the best route to solve this issue, so that I can link my project to Heroku?"—how about trying what the error message says: "Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.6.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling". Does it? If not, what output does it give?

Comment: Chris I have been scouring Stack Overflow for an answer for 4 days, and this is usually where I get stuck, because after running the bash prompt the error tells me to leads to another error. I have updated the question with the result I get back from the prompt.

Comment: Your question hasn't been updated.

Comment: Sorry Chris. For some reason the site kept reading the error message as coding so I had to reformat it.

Comment: Do you have a file `.ruby-version` in your project? If yes, what version are you using?

Comment: Try gem 'puma', '3.6.2'. I think '=> 3.6.2' is not supported. See supported options https://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html

Comment: @Jedi the version of ruby im using is 2.5.6 in my gemfile. I used those characters only to see if specificity would help with the bundle install. Originally I had it as only the numbers without additional characters. I removed them as you said to see if that would make a difference this time, and it didn't. Still getting original error saying that it stalled during puma installation.

Comment: So you switched from system ruby to rvm ruby? Try `rvm uninstall 2.5.6`, `rvm install 2.5.6`. Alternatively, you can try reinstalling rvm and installing ruby again. Also try just `gem 'puma'`

Comment: I have gotta admit, I have used ```rvm uninstall``` both for my original ruby version and the updated one, and ```rvm install 2.5.6```. I did it again cuz I wanted to follow your instructions. I also changed the gemfile for puma as you described. Everything started to work like magic when I ran ```bundle install```. I tried everything. I believe taking away the version specificity of puma must have done it. I finally established a link to Heroku. Thank you so much!!!!